# Where can I ask a question about an issue on WordPress hosted on EC2 with ELB?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

**Which Stack Exchange community should I ask help from?**

I'm having mixed content issue. Even though have set the HTTP_X_PROTO check in wp-config.php in order to set $_SERVER[ "HTTPS" ] = "on". Still for dashboard logins I get a mixed-content issue. For the frontend, most styles are loaded properly (styles of new plugins again show the mixed-content issue).

When I asked in [the WordPress Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/873/peter-mortensen) a question that contained mention of [Amazon EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud), I got shot down with 'Please ask in the proper community'. Later on I found the solution & answered my own question. The issue was resolved within scope of WordPress. Then the commentors simply deleted their comments (and also my replies to the comment were deleted).

There is no dedicated community for [Amazon AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services), so I thought to seek help here, to know where to ask the question.

Comment: @rene Can you not read the question? I'm asking where I should ask this!

Comment: Nothing wrong with my abilities to read. Lack of coffee might be a bigger problem.

Comment: Downvotes are not bullying. I'm unsure why your question is being downvoted (especially since rene's first comment has been deleted), but please try not to get too upset about it.

Comment: You can post in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) or in [Wordpress SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com). I think either site will take it.

Comment: @F1Krazy I'm rather disheartened. I'm trying to do the right thing here and I'm getting shutdown.

Comment: @THelper Wordpress would definitely wont take this. A mere mention of AWS in my last question there and I got shot up with 'please ask in proper community' even when issue was only about Wordpress. WIll post in Stackoverflow. Hope they dont send me to Wordpress SE

Comment: It's still rather unclear what your question is, unless you're familiar with the matter. I happen to know what you mean by "I'm having mixed content issue" but I suspect many users don't.

Comment: You might want to try [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=wordpress+mixed+content), but please add more details and try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately the number of "newcomers" and non who attempt to circumvent a question ban on Stack Overflow  and believe their question can be asked on Meta far outnumber those users who genuinely would like to know where they can post their query. If you made it clearer from the start, people would be less likely to jump to conclusions. You wouldn't believe how many wildly off-topic questions are posted daily on MSE.

Comment: @Mari-LouA How clearer can I get, if I start the title of the question with 'Where should I ask question'

Comment: The body of your question suggested that you wanted someone to answer that problem. I've edited to make it clearer the scope of your request.

Comment: @Shailesh _"Wordpress would definitely wont take this"_ You should [edit] your question to add such information, instead of burying it in comments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It was a reply to a comment

Comment: @Shailesh I know, though this information seems to be essential for your problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ added the essential info to the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if that specific question fits on [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Their scope is focused on Development and your issue looks more like a configuration issue.  They do allow

- server configuration for WordPress

but they explicitly forbid:

- generic server configuration and administration

They also rule out support on anything that is hosted on Wordpress.com.

So I suggest to first check the existing questions on WordPress development and if you find similar questions like yours that are not closed and well received, I would post there.

As an alternative, if your problem could be more seen as a generic PHP programming problem, you could try Stack Overflow. I don't think your question is a good fit for Server Fault, so I certainly wouldn't post there.

A somewhat naive [network wide search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=wordpress+elb+aws+ec2) reveals those two sites as well, so my bet isn't way off.

Depending an audience your question might need more details, for example if those styles come from a specific theme / involves specific plugins. You might have left that out here on purpose, which is fine, but if you have that information available I would not hesitate to add it, including the exact errors/resources that cause problems.

Comment: I have prepared a detailed question. Stackoverflow is asking me to wait for 90mins.